# Error while creating MAVEN project in Eclipse(Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

> I am trying to create simple maven project in Eclipse .
>   It is created but while building Workspace it is giving an Error .
>   also there is an error in pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.students.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>students-application</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> This is my pom.xml
>   I am getting an Error as following

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-
     plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in 
     the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
     interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
     not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-
     plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
     Connection refused: no further information to http://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
     resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile 
     (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile 
     (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its 
     dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: 
     ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
     resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
     elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to 
     central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: no 
     further information to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/
     maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-
     plugin-2.3.2.pom
```

> what should I do?

Comment: are you on windows or Linux?

Comment: I am Working on Windows

Comment: *Always* verify that you can build your project from the command line before attempting to import it into an IDE.  This will eliminate most of your problems from the outset. Right now it looks like you may need to configure a proxy in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might me some of "*.lastUpdated" might be blocking your downloads, You need to remove the "*.lastUpdated" and update the maven project.

Locate the {user}/.m2/repository and delete all "*.lastUpdated" files
you can do this by

searching for  *.lastUpdated in %USERPROFILE%.m2 then deleted the files that Eclipse reported as problematic

or

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

once done update your maven project from eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was great help.